# UILabel value not changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have set up a UILabel (declared in .h, linked in IB). In the viewDidAppear method, if I do `myLabel.text=@"";`, it works. But anywhere else I put this same exact line, nothing happens to the label. The label is in a custom cell view controller which another UITableView class uses as its custom cell. So I thought I had to reload the table after making the change, but that didn't work either. Even in the viewWillAppear method it doesn't work-only viewDidAppear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.myLabel.text = @"";
```

Comment: Where are you trying to set the text? In wich method? If its a view life method did you call the [super  ] ?

Comment: Turned it it was some other issue. I think I got it fixed now, thanks :)

Comment: Care to say what the issue was?